# Can sugarorm automatically remove fields that are no more used?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sugarorm

I begin with SugarORM and i've noticed that it can add automatically fields without the need of making sql scripts (just by incrementing the version number in manifest.xml)

Example: ALTER TABLE CLIENT ADD COLUMN PRENOM TEXT before the first use of Client.Save()

Is there a setting to ask SugarORM to remove no more used fields automatically in the same way ?

Answer (score 0):

[ALTER TABLE SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

> `SQLite` supports a limited subset of `ALTER TABLE`. The `ALTER TABLE` command in `SQLite` allows the user to rename a table or to add a new column to an existing table. It is not possible to rename a column, remove a column, or add or remove constraints from a table.

In `SQLite` you can:

(1). create new table as the one you are trying to change (without the column to delete)
(2). copy all data (except the column you want to delete)
(3). drop old table
(4). rename the new table, to the old name.

Because `android-sugarorm` (`sugarorm`) uses `SQLite` underneath, it is not possible use `ALTER TABLE` to remove a column (field), so it is not done automatically.

See also [Migrating database from previous version](http://satyan.github.io/sugar/migration.html)
[SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q11)